# Links not working correctly on Nivo Slider

Tags: html, css, drupal, nivo-slider

I have a site which contains a nivo slider slideshow. Each image is encapsulated in a link, however I cannot click the link.

Please see the slideshow at the following address:
http://www.andrews-autosource.co.uk/

I am using the nivo slider views module for Drupal.

Comment: Not sure about your slider problem but I'd recommend doing something with that background image. 3.2 MB is way too large a file size.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I must have changed it and forgotten to check the size.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to fix this using just CSS. Nivo is copying the images from the `.field-content` elements, but it's not displaying those specific elements. They're being hidden while a new element displays the slides. The links are wrapped around the images that aren't being shown, so you won't be able to fix this in CSS.

You could probably attack this with Javascript, but there must be an option in the Nivo Views settings to fix it. That would be the best solution.